# Spark Structured Streaming: Consume for each micro-batch all data from Kafka's topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I don't know if I'm asking myself the wrong solution to my problem.

The idea is that I have to consume from Kafka two sources of data from two topics. One of them, each micro-batch has to bring all its content. An example could be that I have micro-batch every 10 minutes, and the topic is growing with updates added by Kafka himself. If in the first instant, from 0 to 10, consumption "A" and "B", and for the next instant, from 10 to 20, enters "C" and topic have "A", "B" y "C" data, I would like to consume "A", "B" and "C". Currently, Spark Structured to return

> Batch 0: "A" and "B"
>
> Batch 1: "C"

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time. Greetings,

Comment: Do you mean subscribe to multiple topics? If so, you can pass multiple topics to the subscribe option: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-streaming-queries